# Cocapods update error after commits merge from repo

Tags: git, cocoapods

I have got a problem with my pods in my Swift 3 project.
When I want update pods I can see:

```
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

What I should to do to update pods?

Comment: I put 
$ pod update

Comment: I have solved that problem

Comment: I will leave for another people.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack :)

Comment: No problem, Andrzej, and welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with:

```
pod repo remove master

pod setup
```